# Is it possible to install mariadb 10.3 or mysql 5.7 in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: apt, mysql, 22.04, mariadb

I need to install **mariadb 10.3** or **mysql 5.7** to work with Magento 2.3 project, but I am not able to do this via apt install. It installs only the latest versions of the soft above.

I tried to add `mariadb.list` file with specific versioned repositories into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` folder and re-run apt install, but seems like this is not working.

Could anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can and this is where tarballs show their strength.

You can keep the one from `apt` as its own installation but I consider it more logical to then install that one from a tarball too.

How I have done it in the past:

The directory to use is `/opt/` as this is intended for installing source versions of 3rd party applications. You download the tarballs of all the versions you want and unpack each of them in `/opt/` (links to the tarballs below). The directories in `/opt/` will be created when unpacking the tarball and will all look like "{packagename}-{version}.{subversion}". The permissions will all be correctly set, the directory will have its own configuration, and its own database.

You can also set a port for each of the versions you want to use otherwise you need to shutdown the previous one before using the next one. That way you can switch in real time by updating `/opt/sql` to another version.

So you get this kind of chain:

```
/dir_included_in_$PATH/mysql symlinks to ...
    /opt/sql symlinks to one of ...
        /opt/mysql-5.6/{executable} 
        /opt/mysql-5.7/{executable}
        /opt/mysql-8.0/{executable}
        /opt/mariadb-10.3/{executable}
```

(all names are optional so if you want other names feel free to adjust)

Tarballs:

- [MySQL](https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/)
- [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-binary-tarballs/)

In the installation instructions of each of the downloads there will be a method (look for `ln -s`) to connect the binary to the one in your systems PATH but here you deviate a little and connect it to `/opt/sql` where `/opt/sql` is the one connected to the mysql in your systems PATH. So it will be one extra symlink.

There are some issues though: not all databases are interchangeable between SQL releases. MySQL 8 has, by default, more restrictions on valid date formats then 5.7 or older and will error out if your software is not up to this default (iirc 0000-00-00 is no longer allowed; it needs to be 0001-01-01). So your software needs to follow the most restrictive version you install to work on all.